# Event after rendering the activity

Tags: android-layout

I have created an activity that builds a TableLayout dynamically in the onCreate event. But i would like to know if it's possible to know when the system has finished the activity rendering.

When the layout is created statically by XML, we can to do any action in the onLayout event, but seems that when it's created dinamically i have to wait more time or wait for another event until full TableLayout rendering is done.

Any ideas??

Regards

Comment: Solved redesigning layout and using onLayout method. Thanks and regards

Comment: Could you please give little piece of code? I can't find any onLayout event in Activity class.